# docker influxdb restore db on start up

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Docker newbie here.

I would like to start an docker influxdb instance with restored database.

I have backed up the data I want to restore. Now I would like to restore the influx database when I call docker-compose.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM influxdb:1.7.4-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY entrypoint.sh ./

COPY backedUpInfluxDBFolder /tmp/backedUpInfluxDBFolder

RUN chmod u+x entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And entrypoint.sh is populated as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ ! -f "/var/lib/influxdb/.init" ]; then
    exec influxd $@ &

    until wget -q "http://localhost:8086/ping" 2> /dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done

    influx -host=localhost -port=8086 -execute="CREATE USER ${INFLUX_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${INFLUX_PASSWORD}' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"

    touch "/var/lib/influxdb/.init"

    kill -s TERM %1
fi

exec influxd $@
```

I would like to call the following command inside entrypoint.sh

```
influxd restore -portable /tmp/backedUpInfluxDBFolder
```

I have tried putting the influxd command inside the if statement but that doesn't seem to work. it creates the database, but it doesn't populate it.

I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the backup file in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d inside the container.

Change:

```
COPY backedUpInfluxDBFolder /tmp/backedUpInfluxDBFolder
```

to

```
COPY backedUpInfluxDBFolder/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I don't know Influx, but I assume the backup folder contains sql files? (my solution is based on this assumption).

Hope this helps.